# I can't see scroll bar to left and right until I scroll all the way down to the bottom of the content

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to add scroll controls to my pdf viewer. Scroll up and down works fine but I can't see the bar for scrolling left and right until I scroll to the bottom of the pdf file. In my css I have:

```
.pdf-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

In my html, I have:

```
<div class="pdf-content" [style.width]="imageWidth" [style.height]="imageHeight">
    <pdf-viewer *ngIf="fileUrl" style="display: block;" 
        [src]="fileUrl" 
        [show-all]="false" 
        [original-size]="false" 
        [rotation]="rotation"
        [page]="page"
        [zoom]="zooming"
        (after-load-complete)="callBackFn($event)">
    </pdf-viewer>

    <md-spinner *ngIf="loadingPdf && fileUrl" class="center"></md-spinner>
</div>
```

[image: When I'm in the middle of the pdf, I don't see the bottom scroll bar]

[image: If I scroll all the way down, I can see the bottom scroll bar]

Comment: Have you tried to add overflow-x:scroll; or just change the overflow-y to be  only overflow?

Comment: @Apolymoxic Yes I did try both. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll bars are on two different elements. Try changing `overflow-y: auto` to just `overflow: auto` so that the scroll bars are on the same element.

Comment: Not much I can say without seeing it in action.  All you can do is inspect (or firebug) and check each element and see whats going on, experiment